# Custom popup view in Swift (Interface Builder)

Tags: swift, uiview, popup

Is there any way I can show a custom popup in the middle of the screen (over the current content) with buttons and a textfield and anything else I may need, entirely in interface builder?

If this isn't possible, then I don't mind doing it programatically.

I am guessing you create a custom view with the content but I am not sure how I show that view when a button is clicked and bring it up over the current view controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a View and a Viewcontroller for it- set the alpha of the view to zero so its invisible - then but a nice picture as background for the custom popuop on it ( as background for the popup) on this i would put the buttons and the text label. Voilà - costum pop-up is ready to present with a segue (choose type over the current view controller).